# encoded item url empty

Tags: workflow, ootb

I have a library-DocLibrary which has one column itemURL of type single line of text. I am setting value of this column by using workflow. The workflow sets the

> itemURL

column value for the current item by using Current Item : Encoded Item URL.

But even after successful execution of the workflow, the column value shows blank(Empty) if the file is a word document. For PDF, it works fine.

Can anyone please suggest me how can I generate URL of word document.

Thanks

Comment: I am using nintex workflow

Comment: using the action "Set Field in current Item" with value "Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL" to generate url of pdf file.

Comment: but for word files it is not generating